# Error installing MySQL: Unable to update security settings

Tags: windows, mysql

Get this error while trying to install MySQL (as a administrator):

[image: Unable to update security settings]

I've chosen for just one account, the root-account.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Please check root access and firewall.

To fix this :

```
 Ran it on a machine with full root acces
 Added all MySQL items to firewall list and ran reconfiguration of the MySQL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.I've less knowledge about configuring Windows, how can I add items to the firewall list?